# Change in copied object reflects in source cell on handontable drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am having object

```
  var x1 = {T1: 'Test1', Y1: 'TestY1'};
  var x2 = {T1: 'Test2', Y1: 'TestY2'};
  var x3 = {T1: 'Test3', Y1: 'TestY3'};

  var data = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Ted', isActive: x1},
      {id: 2, name: 'John', isActive: x2},
      {id: 3, name: 'Al', isActive: x3}
    ]
```

I bind this data to handontable.
I want to do some modification in destination object on drag.

```
beforeAutofill = function (start, end, data) {
                data[0][0].T1 = 'tt1';         
    };
```

This code should change only row 1, from test2 to tt1.

But it changes both rows(0 and 1) to tt1.

I think it is issue of shallow copy object of source.

http://jsfiddle.net/hemantmalpote/LLyd9d7s/